# Is constantly promoting our own posts by linking them in our own posts and/or in chat messages considered a fair practice?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, chat, self-promotion

First of all, since I post primarily on [Hinduism SE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com), all my example posts are taken from that site.

Secondly, all the example posts, that I am using in this post, are linked to one user only. But, I can't really do anything about it. Because without giving those examples, it's not possible for me to present my point.

**Examples of promoting our own posts by adding their links in another post:**

In [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19692/did-the-samkhya-school-discuss-the-danger-of-yagna-fires-to-surrounding-wildlife), the author provides links of his 4 other questions. And, in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10190/has-the-paramatmika-upanishad-ever-been-translated-into-english), the author provides links of 7 of his other posts (both questions and answers).

The number of such posts are actually [numerous](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=As+i+discuss+user%3A36).

1. Is the practice considered a fair one?

**Examples where we are promoting our posts in chat room messages:**

In [this chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/38640?m=41953166#41953166) and in [this message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/38640?m=42362963#42362963), the author is pinging other users so that they can become aware of the posts that he has just made.

Again, the number of such instances are [numerous](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?room=38640&q=I%20just%20posted).

2. Is this practice considered fair?

Are these considered as promotional tactics and are they considered as fair as per SE guidelines? Given the fact that they are being done repeatedly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For sites - if the links are relevant, it helps others find the related posts - assuming OP's got *sufficient* information for the post to stand on its own. I'd treat it much like I'd treat any offsite reference, whether its OP's own resource or something relevant elsewhere.

For chat - This is *really* something that should be discussed on your chat.

In *many* chatrooms, posting posts for *attention* is considered deeply impolite - however, what works well for a reasonably busy chatroom, on a major site dealing with tech might not work as well on hinduism.se.

The *core* of getting this to work is to get buy in from *mods* who frequent the room, room regulars and ROs - if you're free to remind the user politely, it smacks of self promotion, and that there's ways to get attention for posts, eventually they get the idea.

Downvotes help too.

In short there's no solution that works well here - consider context and well, talking out like adults. There's no need for specific rules for such things.

Comment: I agree with your answer partially but not fully. For example, don't you think that the fact- for **each** of my 100s of questions, i'll **always** require to take help of at least 4 of my **own** posts to provide context- is kind of absurd? And more so since it is happening always? So, i am neither downvoting nor upvoting your post.

Comment: which is fine - I *personally* feel in your examples, he's creating a link between related topics *and* covering potential people pointing out potential dupes. He's basically going "I want this - and its different from this, this *and* this" in the specific example you gave.  Considering this feels like a *lightly* veiled question about a specific user - perhaps you should have a word with him too?

Comment: Ok. And no it's not about a user. Apart from knowing if it's acceptable or not, i also wanted to know if this practice is widely seen on other SE sites or not.

Comment: @Rickross It's fairly common to link to other related posts. For example, on ELU.SE, we have a retired English professor who writes the most amazing answers, and he links to his own journals/articles hosted on the university website. It's not self-promotion; it's showing a way for readers to learn more.

Comment: @NVZ i can understand that we may need to do that when we are writing answers. In Hinduism SE, we most of the time cite directly from the scriptures (it is mandatory to do so while writing answers). But we can very well cite one of our own answers, if it is having the verses which will answer the current question. But, the point here is that all my example posts are questions and not answers. But anyways, thanks for participating in the discussion.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's "promoting" own posts, but rather pointing to something the user already discussed in one of their 1000s of posts. This helps avoid saying the same thing over and over again.

If done right, it's a good thing to link to other related posts. For example, on ELU.SE, we have a retired English professor who writes the most amazing answers, and he links to his own journals/articles hosted on the university website. It's not self-promotion; it's showing a way for readers to learn more.

In other ways, if the user were to randomly link to their posts here and there, that would be not cool. About the ones linked in the chat, I am not sure, because I don't know the history between the tagged users and the author. Maybe they have a close friendship. I don't know. Tagging random users and linking to own posts would not be acceptable however.

Comment: And in the chats?

Comment: In chat it depends on what the room owners allow, in SOCVR for example we don't allow it and move such messages to trash. In the Tavern here on MSE there is no such rule, but don't annoy me and the other regulars too much with such posts.

Comment: The OP tags always pings same users in chat. The tagged users don't have any problem with pinging them. They chat regularly.Some of the users also asked the OP to ping them when he posts questions of that tag.

Answer (score 3):

I support [@NVZ's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/305996/357396) here. If the post provides a context on what is discussed in the question, why not?

If a user links their own or other user's posts which help understand, that should be fine. As I know the writing style of that author (I too am a frequent user of Hinduism.SE), he asks questions which are not often discussed by normal users. I should say that if there are no linking posts, it would be difficult to understand his questions for a novice. Hence, I don't see much of a problem here. Linking questions/answers to provide context and understand the questions better is fine. Our help center page actually says to add what we have found while writing questions. From [How do I ask a good question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) which is often shared as a guideline for newbies on the site,

> Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? **Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself**, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

But if a user is constantly adding their own posts again and again and the post stands without those links, they can be removed by editing.

- If you feel those are unnecessary and making making the post lengthy, you may contact the user in chat or in the comments and ask them to remove.
- Length of the post should not be the only reason to downvote. They should be voted based on whole merit instead of a single word.
- Every person has an own style of writing. Some use their own phrases, some use highly sophisticated language. Similarly, some users have a habit of adding a link of writing an introduction like sentence. You may also skip those sentences and continue from important portion (This is what I do for lengthy announcement posts and Meta discussions). As I said above, a post doesn't deserve votes just on its length.

In chat, the Room Owners and regular users should discuss this. So, that is the correct place to discuss. As I was also a regular user when those messages were posted and still the frequent user of that room, I think I have my two cents to drop in this particular instance. This particular user has a habit of pinging users interested in a topic. That has turned into a pun and a recurring meme in the room's chat. Few users continued this and there are still such messages going on.

Now, is pinging users in chat a problem? I don't think so. It is a problem if the user doesn't like. It is not a problem until the users are interested. This is what I observed 95% of times. One [message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41133490#41133490) was like this (from a user who was pinged in the question):

> Good question on Purva-Mimamsa, please consider notifying me in this room whenever you post questions on purva-mimamsa if it's not a hassle to begin with

In many rooms, users post their questions and answers. They do not necessarily do it for votes but for feedback from fellow users hanging out, edits which increase quality. In chat, many rooms have feeds and bots activated to post questions from main site into chat. Few specific rooms have questions only from a few topics (like the one you added in the chat room) not to miss out them. So, this is subjective. If we have a problem, we can always ignore. But from Stack Exchange, there is no prohibition of posting such messages in chat. [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) says the following [from [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7054/357396)]:

> Post a link to the question on the site's chat. Usually active users of the site will hang out there, and they can offer further help.

Having said that, do not use this feature *just* to get attention and votes from users. Don't just drop in links without any context in some site's chat. There are users who consider pinging as a noise. Frequent posting in an unrelated chat room without context could also receive warnings. So, post only in related chat rooms when there is a context. That too when the users are interested.